# Does Spark SQL consider limit when join?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I did the following experiment.

Query 1:

```
 select f1, f2 from A where id = 10 limit 1

 | f1  |  f2  |
 --------------
 |  1  |  2   |
```

Query 2:

```
 select * from B as b where b.f1 = 1 and b.f2 = 2 limit 1
```

Both Query 1 and Query 2 run very fast.

However when I did the following

```
 select B.* 
 from B join A 
 on B.f1 = A.f1 and B.f2 = A.f2 
 where A.id = 10 limit 1
```

It runs slow with many stages and tasks...

I had assumed the last query will not be much expensive than query 1 and query 2 given 'limit 1'. Its plan is like the following. Does this indicate that the limit 1 is used only after all join are finished...?

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 1
+- LocalLimit 1
   +- Join Inner, ((obj_id#352L = obj_id#342L) && (obj_type#351 = obj_type#341))
      :- Project [uid#350L, obj_type#351, obj_id#352L]
      :  +- Filter ...
      :     +- Relation[...] parquet
      +- Aggregate [obj_id#342L, obj_type#341], [obj_id#342L, obj_type#341]
         +- Project [obj_type#341, obj_id#342L]
            +- Filter ...
               +- Relation[...] parquet
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the limit 1 only applies after the other operations are completed.
So in all of your queries above, the entire 'table' would be generated and then one row would be picked out and returned.
Your join will create the cartesian product from your table B and A based on your where clause, and then limit 1.

Comment: @DanCarter Thank you. Although it seems not unnecessary to do so...

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: I use spark 2.4